# Understanding SourceName in Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

I have a question regarding the meaning of `SourceName` in `parse` function in `Parsec`. It seems that all books/blogs/tutorials I read just skip what it is and use `"stdin"`, `"(stdin)"` or an arbitrary string such as `"test parser"`. Does it make any difference what is specified as a `SourceName`?

I tried to read the [source code](https://github.com/haskell/parsec) of `Parsec` and it seems that it is used for creating a position. But why does it matter what source it is (as a `String` indeed). It sounds that I do not need to worry about it in most cases.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are writing e.g. a compiler which processes many files at once, this setting is relevant for parse error reporting - obviously one wants to know what file an error occurs in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Parsec, `SourceName` is a `String` that's used for generating error messages. When in the REPL, this is not very important:

```
λ> parse expression "<stdin>" ")"
Left "<stdin>" (line 1, column 1):
unexpected ")"
expecting expression
```

If we used `"foo"` instead of `"<stdin>"`, if would look like this instead:

```
Left "foo" (line 1, column 1):
unexpected ")"
expecting expression
```

This is useful when writing a program that takes multiple files as input, like a compiler or interpreter. For example, in my interpreter, I have the following function:

```
runFile :: FilePath -> IO ()
runFile path = do code  <- readFile path
                  start <- prelude
                  evalString path start code >>= putStrLn
```

Here I'm passing `path`—the path of the file you're running—into the function which parses the expression. This way, the error message will tell you *which* file has the parse error, along with the line numbers.

```
λ> runFile "/Users/tikhon/tmp/foo.tpl"
Error: "/Users/tikhon/tmp/foo.tpl" (line 1, column 1):
unexpected ')'
expecting expression or end of input!
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you, Tikhon! In summary, if my parser reads from a single source, e.g., STDIN, or a file, it actually does not matter much.